# how to specify jmx mbean to render it as a tree in jconsole?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

My application has a specific set of keys for which I monitor values(min, max, etc..). It looks very similar to the following:

```
 public class Data implements Serializable{
    int max, min; //etc..
 }

 public interface HelloMBean{
     String [] getKeys();
     Data getDataForKey(String);
     Data [] getDatas();
 }
```

However, I am not able to see the Keys or Datas attribute using jconsole(I always see a 'not available' value for those properties).

How should I structure my bean definition so that it would displayed as a tree of values ?

```
HelloMBean
|- attributes
     |---- key1
     |---- key2
```

I would like to display the values(eg: key1.max or key2.min) as a graph as well. Is this possible? If so, what would be the best way to achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the `javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData` that you want?

It is "unavailable" because the jconsole doesn't have `Data` class available, it doesn't know anything about the class.

Or if you want create each "key" as separate attribute, you could make your own implementation of the `DynamicMBean` which returns simple structures with primitive types like `int`. E.g. there is [example here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2006/11/a_real_example.html).

Comment: any clue as to how would I go about using the `CompositeData` class with Spring?

Comment: @Yaneeve As I understand the `CompositeData` is automatically supported if you create a MXBean properly (no `Map` support however). The http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html documentation has very similar example. The code quite trivial, no need of the Spring. If you want the map exposed as list of attributes, I think you have to implement `DynamicMBean`, no support from the Spring either.

Comment: I would like to use spring as it easily lets me configure the MBean names, etc, via a configuration file. I would like to have consumer code set this file according to their needs. I understand from what you write that Spring does not support DynamicMBeans, but does it or does it not support MXBeans?

Comment: @Yaneeve The code is very trivial, you could put mxbean's stuff as spring config. The MBean is limited by types, however: *The MXBean concept provides a simple way to code an MBean that only references a predefined set of types*

Comment: @Yaneeve In common case... not everything requires the Spring® Support™, any reasonable designed java classes could be configured by the Spring.